# Copy-paste hotkeys in Chrome devtools

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

In windows I can use `Ctrl+C`/`Ctrl+V` hotkeys to copy/paste html elements in Elements tab (without switching to `Edit as HTML` mode). In MacOS I can only make it by `Right Click on elem` >> `Copy` >> `Copy Element`. Can I turn on `Cmd+C`/`Cmd+V` hotkeys for that?

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasting nodes in the Elements tab works perfectly fine on MacOS with `Cmd+C` and `Cmd+V`. Here's the GIF,

[image]